# Picture box always throws object reference not set to instance of object error

Tags: c#

I have a class which holds a picturebox. I have created an array of objects of my class, but when I try to create a new picture box, I am getting an error stating, object reference is not set to an instance of object.

Here is how I am creating pictureboxes

```
 GreyHound[] dog;

    public Form1()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       dog[1].MyPictureBox = new PictureBox();
       dog[1].MyPictureBox = pictureBox1;

       dog[2].MyPictureBox = new PictureBox();
       dog[2].MyPictureBox = pictureBox2;

       dog[3].MyPictureBox = new PictureBox();
       dog[3].MyPictureBox = pictureBox3;

       dog[4].MyPictureBox = new PictureBox();
       dog[4].MyPictureBox = pictureBox4;
```

Edited Code :

GreyHound[] dog;

```
    public Form1()
    {

       InitializeComponent();
       dog = new GreyHound[4];
       dog[0].MyPictureBox = new PictureBox();
       dog[0].MyPictureBox = pictureBox1;

       dog[1].MyPictureBox = new PictureBox();
       dog[1].MyPictureBox = pictureBox2;

       dog[2].MyPictureBox = new PictureBox();
       dog[2].MyPictureBox = pictureBox3;

       dog[3].MyPictureBox = new PictureBox();
       dog[3].MyPictureBox = pictureBox4;



    }
```

Comment: This is just an excerpt

Comment: And if it doesn't make any sense, then I expect you guys can put me on the right track, instead of negatively rating the question.

Comment: I already removed that comment and provided an answer instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16785614/572644

Comment: thanks..I have initialized the array but it is still not working.

Comment: Please read my whole answer and perform all the steps. I have updated it since I posted that comment. If that doesn't help, please post the exact error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you have has several severe problems:

1. The reason for your `NullReferenceException` is two-fold:

   1. You declare an array of `GreyHound`, but you never initialize it. That means, that `dog` is `null` and trying to access `dog[1]` results in a NullReferenceException.
   2. If you would fix that, you would still have another problem:
        Assuming that `GreyHound` is a reference type that means that you will have to create an instance for each item in the array. With your current code, all items in the array are `null` which leads to a `NullReferenceException` when trying to access the property `MyPictureBox` on any item in the array, because `dog[1]` would be `null`.
2. For every item in the array, you first assign a new instance of a `PictureBox` to the property `MyPictureBox` but you overwrite that value in the very next line with `pictureBoxX`.
3. As we are in C#, arrays are zero indexed, so the first item has the index 0 and not 1.

Fix your code like so:

```
GreyHound[] dog = new GreyHound[4]; // solves problem 1.1

dog[0] = new GreyHound(); // solves problem 1.2
dog[0].MyPictureBox = pictureBox1;

dog[1] = new GreyHound(); // solves problem 1.2
dog[1].MyPictureBox = pictureBox2;

dog[2] = new GreyHound(); // solves problem 1.2
dog[2].MyPictureBox = pictureBox3;

dog[3] = new GreyHound(); // solves problem 1.2
dog[3].MyPictureBox = pictureBox4;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem has been solved, and now I also understood where I wennt wrong. Thanks again for explaining it perfectly :)

Answer (score 2):

You do not initialize you array anywhere:

```
dog = new GreyHound[4];
```

also array indexing starts from 0 so:

```
dog[0].MyPictureBox = new PictureBox();
dog[0].MyPictureBox = pictureBox1;

dog[1].MyPictureBox = new PictureBox();
dog[1].MyPictureBox = pictureBox2;

dog[2].MyPictureBox = new PictureBox();
dog[2].MyPictureBox = pictureBox3;

dog[3].MyPictureBox = new PictureBox();
dog[3].MyPictureBox = pictureBox4;
```